An invariant subspace for the adjoints of Kraus operators is a reducing subspace for the Kraus operators themselves.
This might be a long shot, but I am completely flummoxed.
I am trying to understand the proof of Theorem III.4. The theorem uses a lemma that states  "an invariant subspace for the adjoints of Kraus operators is a reducing subspace for the Kraus operators themselves". This lemma is stated without proof in the paper. However, the statement "an invariant subspace for a set Kraus operators is a reducing subspace for those Kraus operators" is proven, and it states in the paper that it is this result that is used in the proof of Theorem III.4. I don't know whether I am just not parsing things correctly, whether there is a typo in the paper, or whether the proof of the result that (as it seems to me) is actually being used is so obvious, that the authors did not bother to state it.
That is, it seems to me that (vi) => (ii) is being used, while (iv) => (ii) is the statement that was proved and that the paper claims to be using...in any case, it is claimed that all six statements are equivalent for a unital channel, but I don't see how to prove (vi) => (ii).
If anyone can help me prove Theorem III.4, prove the lemma that (as it seems to me) is being used, explain to me why I am wrong in my understanding of what is happening, point out how the lemma that is proved is sufficient to prove Theorem III.4...any or all of the above...I would be eternally grateful. I've been beating my head against this for too long.
Hopefully the question is intelligible at least.
Attached is a picture of the proof of the theorem, and a picture of the lemma and the proof that is given, as well as a link to the paper.
Paper here: https://arxiv.org/pdf/quant-ph/0402056





If $A_k^*P=PA_k^*P$ for all $k$, then
$$
P=\sum_kA_kA_k^*P=\sum_kA_kPA_k^*P=\Phi(P)P.
$$
Then $P\leq\Phi(P)$ (by the Lemma at the bottom). They also have equal trace, so $P=\Phi(P)$.
Thus
$$
0=(I-P)P(I-P)=\sum_k(I-P)A_kPA_k^*(I-P).
$$
As all the terms in the sum are positive, for each $k$
$$
0=(I-P)A_kPA_k^*(I-P)=(I-P)A_kP\,[(I-P)A_kP]^*.
$$
Then $0=(I-P)A_kP$, which is $A_kP=PA_kP$. Since we had $PA_k=PA_kP$ as hypothesis,
$$
PA_k=A_kP\qquad\text{ for all } k. 
$$

Lemma. Let $B\geq0$, $Q$ a nonzero projection such that $Q=BQ$. Then $Q\leq B$.
Proof. We have $B^nQ=Q$ for all $n$, so $p(B)Q=p (1)Q$ for all polynomials $p$. Let
$$
B=\sum_j\beta_jR_j
$$
be the spectral decomposition of $B$, with $\beta_1,\ldots,\beta_m$ distinct. Let $p$ be real and such that $p(\beta_k)=1$ and $p(\beta_j)=0$ for $j\ne k$. Then $p(1)Q=R_kQ$. As $p(1)$ is real, taking adjoints we see that $R_kQ=QR _k$. Then
$$
p(1)^2Q=R_kQR_kQ=R_kQ=p (1)Q.
$$
So $p(1)\in\{0,1\}$. This means that either $R_kQ=0$ or $R_kQ=Q $. If $R_kQ=Q=R_jQ$ for $k\ne j$, then $Q=Q^2=R_kR_jQ=0$, a contradiction.
We have thus shown that $B=\beta Q+S$ with $S\geq0$. And $Q=BQ=\beta Q$, so $\beta=1$. Hence $B\geq Q$. $\ \ \Box$

Sorry, why do we have $\sum_kA_kA_k^P=\sum_kA_kPA_k^$?

It's not obvious, I added some details.

Thank you! I am finding that these types of operator theory results are quite difficult to wrap my head around. Do you have a suggestion for a reference/textbook for self-study? I'm looking at A Course in Functional Analysis and A Course in Operator Theory by Conway at the moment, and they seem quite approachable.

Conway is a good book, but for stuff like this you need familiarity with von Neumann algebras, where you deal with projections all the time. For this, there is no super easy path. Chapters 5, 6, and 7 of Kadison-Ringrose are fairly comprehensive, though not an easy read. Murphy has a bit on von Neumann algebras, maybe that's better for a start. There are many other texts, but I wouldn't know how to compare them.
